# Redux Middleware with Socket io

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io

Just tried to create a simple chat application using react JS, redux, and socketIO. After exploring for some time I found that it is good to have a **Redux middleware** so that I can manage the socket connections and data.
After a bit of research, I came up with the following solution

`socketMiddleware.js`

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

//This acts as middleware for all store actions.
const socketMiddleware = () => {
    console.log("MIDDDLEWARE")
  let webSocket = null;
  // the middleware part of this function

  return store => next => action => {


    switch (action.type) {
        case 'WS_CONNECT':
          webSocket = socketIOClient(action.host);
          webSocket.on("connection_success", data => {
            console.log("ON Connect : ",data);
          })
          webSocket.on("new_message", messageData => {
              console.log("NEW MESSAGE : ",messageData)
            })
        
        case "SEND_MESSAGE":
          webSocket.emit("received_new_message", action.payload)
          console.log('Message Send');        
    }  
    


    return next(action);
  };
};

export default socketMiddleware();
```

This works as intended, but my question is, Is there any better solution than this (Of course. There should be)?

Comment: Unless you're supporting old browsers, like JQuery, Socket.io is not as useful as it used to be and adds unnecessary bloat since [**WebSockets**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) became mainstream.

Comment: both should be implemented in same manner. I guess?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 is that possible to create chat rooms from `WebSockets`  ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!  You can create chat rooms with WebSockets.